# Hide the password textbox and submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is a simple password checking function I messed around with for a little bit. I've tried a lot of different methods (including, but not limited to: .css(), .on('click'), .click(), .animate(), .show(), .hide(), .preventDefault() on the submit), put selectors into variables, moved around all sorts of `IDs` and `$('input[name="s"]')` and all sorts of selectors. Not sure if the function won't work, or maybe something else within the script. I've taken the function out of the `$(document).ready()` tree, and moved it all around inside of it. I'm sure that isn't the problem now, but I'm starting to not be sure about anything at this point.

I'm trying to get the function to hide the password textbox and submit(or is button better?) and show a textarea for news input, with a button to append the update.The appendedTo and .append() section works, but I can't seem to get the passwordcheck function to work. Sometimes it will alert me if it's wrong, but when it's right the  `if` methods don't seem to work. Then I'll change it a few times and the alert will no longer show, nor will the `if` work any longer.

Any help would be appreciated, and I can provide any code snippets or chunks at request.

Function in question:

```
function passwordcheck() {
        var $newspass = $('#newspass');
        var $submitpass = $('#submitpass'); // <--- variables were at one point selectors
        var $newssubmit = $('#newssubmit');     //    written out, I've changed this a lot
        if ($newspass.val() === 'comecorrecT') {
                $submitpass.css('display', 'hidden');
                $newspass.css('display', 'hidden');
                $('#newsinput').css('display', 'block');
                $newssubmit.css('display', 'static');
        } else {
            alert("Try again, please.");

        }
    };
```

Rest of the script, for reference:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// billboard functions
    var $billboard = $('.billboard');
    $billboard.mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).fadeTo('slow', 0.98);
        });
    $billboard.mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).fadeTo('slow', 0.72);
        });
    var $learn = $('#learn-more');
    $learn.hover(function(){
        $(this).fadeTo('slow', 1);
        }, 
    function() {
        $(this).fadeTo('slow', 0.6);
        });
// news and updates/appendedTo
    var $submitpass = $('#submitpass');
    var $newssubmit = $('#newssubmit');
    $submitpass.click(passwordcheck());
    $newssubmit.click(function(){
        $('#appendedTo').append('<div class="update">'+$('#newsinput').val()+'</div>');
// passwordcheck();
        });
    });
```

I've been working with it for a little while now, and I know you guys will have a profound explanation or two.

Comment: What about the script doesn't work?

Comment: Wow, forgot to add that. I'll edit it.

Comment: Somewhat off-topic, but - never do passwords on clientside. Anyone can see your source code, and your password is right there, plain as day.

Comment: wow password :3 kappa

Comment: Thank you, @Amadan . I do realize that haha, I'm just doing this on my local server to practice my script/query and just really develop the skills I already have. And right now, I'm really getting into jquery and javascript, but self-teaching is difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you are doing it now, you are simply passing "undefined" instead of a function (which would be what the passwordcheck function returns) as you are calling the function instead of passing a reference to it in this line:

```
$submitpass.click(passwordcheck());
```

Which should be

```
$submitpass.click(passwordcheck);
```

In the last block of your code, after

```
// news and updates/appendedTo
```

This being said, don't use client side JavaScript for authentication, the password you are checking against is visible for anyone using the site.

Comment: Is that honestly the answer? It took me a while to come to that, but I was just thinking about it about an hour ago and thought to myself, "that's mad". I read about functions and calling/referring is starting to make more and more sense. Thank you!

Comment: Most likely, yes. The way you are doing it now, you are simply passing "undefined" as the click handler, which would be the result of the passwordcheck function.

Comment: I should have run it through a console or something in stead of testing it in my local html file, huh? But thanks again, man. That worked like a charm.

Comment: You're welcome! Allways use the console for development! It will save you a lot of time... ;) @PhilC.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function passwordcheck() {
        var newspass = $('#newspass').val();
        var submitpass = $('#submitpass').val();
        var newssubmit = $('#newssubmit').val();
        if (newspass == 'comecorrecT') {
                $('#submitpass').hide();
                $('#newspass').hide();
                $('#newsinput').show();
        } else {
            alert("Try again, please.");

        }
    }
```

Comment: It's always best to explain what you did to fix the problem, not just a *try this*.

Comment: It seems I was calling when I should have been referring. But I see now that these methods are a lot more dependable than the .css() method.